# Can I use anonymous types from linq results to create a collection of classes as part of a method parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm selecting some data from a source and I want to pass this to a generic method for handling the data. Each property I select needs a little bit of meta-data associated for processing. This is roughly what I'd like to be able to do:

```
var items = from i in db.bar
            select new {
                a = i.Prop1.ToString(),
                b = i.Prop2.ToString(),
                c = Prop3
            };

// Roughly what I would like to be able to do:
ProcessData(items,
    new DataSelector() { Header = "head1", Selector = (d => d.Prop1) },
    new DataSelector() { Header = "head2", Selector = (d => d.Prop2) });
```

The closest I can get is the following:

```
private class DataSelector<T> {
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public Func<T, string> Selector { get; set; }
}

private static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff,
                               params ColumnDef<T>[] defs) {
    foreach (var item in stuff) {
         // Use all defs like...
         Console.WriteLine(defs[0].Header + ": " + defs[0].Selector(item));
    }
}

Process(items,
    new DataSelector<dynamic>() { Header = "head1", Selector = (d => d.Prop1) });
```

But this allows me to write `(d => d.NonExistantProp)` and it will compile and fail at runtime (boo, hiss). I can also do it for a single property and maintain type safety because the type seems to be worked out implicitly, but that won't let me pass sets of parameters:

```
private static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff,
                               string header,
                               Func<T, string> selector) {
     // stuff happens
}

Process(items, "head1", (d => d.Prop1));
```

So... Is there a way to maintain compile-time type safety of the selector along with groups of related data?

Footnote: I appreciate I could have `Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, List<string> headers, params Func<T, string> selectors[])` but that also produces run-time errors if the headers don't pair up to the selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some way of creating a `DataSelector` that uses type inference based on a given sequence (or item, or anything else that uses the type).

We can create a non-generic DataSelector counterpart that can have a static `Create` method that can be written in such a way as to allow type inference:

```
private class DataSelector
{
    public static DataSelector<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence,
        string header, Func<T, string> selector)
    {
        return new DataSelector<T>() { Header = header, Selector = selector };
    }
}
```

Now the caller can write:

```
Process(items, DataSelector.Create(items, "first", item => item.Prop1));
```

And we are now inferring the type of `T` for the data selector and don't need to specify a type that has no name.

Note that we're not actually iterating the sequence in this `Create` method; it's not used at all; it's basically a dummy parameter.

This is a pattern that we see used in a number of places in the .NET framework, such as for `Tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>` instead of anonymous class:

```
var items = db.bar.AsEnumerable().Select(c=>Tuple.Create(i.Prop1, i.Prop2, i.Prop3));

ProcessData(items,
    new DataSelector<Tuple<T1,T2,T3>>("head1", d => d.Prop1.ToString()),
    new DataSelector<Tuple<T1,T2,T3>>("head2", d => d.Prop2.ToString()));


private class DataSelector<T>
    {
        public DataSelector(string header, Func<T, string> selector)
        {
            Header = header;
            Selector = selector;
        }

        public string Header { get; set; }
        public Func<T, string> Selector { get; set; }
    }

private static void Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> stuff,
                               params ColumnDef<T>[] defs) 
{
    foreach (var item in stuff) {
         // Use all defs like...
         Console.WriteLine(defs[0].Header + ": " + defs[0].Selector(item));
    }
}
```